# SQL Server 2017 - EF is trying to access different database than in connection string

Tags: entity-framework, high-availability, sql-server-2017

I have a very awkward situation, and I have no idea how to tackle it.

Here are the details.

I have three SQL Server 2017 instances, which are used with a production database configured with High Availability.

The servers are SRV1, SRV2 and SRV3

I have a production database named DB1, configured with High Availability as follows:
- main node (r/w) on SRV1
- secondary nodes (r/o) on SRV2 and SRV3

Also on SRV3 I have a staging copy of the database named DB1_DEMO

From time to time we restore production data in DB1_DEMO, for fresh test data.

Also I keep a local development copy of database, on my local dev machine, named also DB1, which I use to refresh the EF model.

The app uses EF6 with db-first approach.
When we do some changed to database, we refresh the EF model (edmx).

The problem, which started recently, is the following:

Even if on the staging copy of the application I have the correct connection string (pointing to SRV3 and DB1_DEMO), when I run some SPs (using ADO.NET or EF), I get the following error:

```
The target database ('DB1') is in an availability group and is currently
accessible for connections when the application intent is set to read only.
For more information about application intent, see SQL Server Books Online.
```

But the code doesn't access database DB1, but DB1_DEMO.

The connection string points clearly to DB1_DEMO.

```
<add name="MpnModelDC" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.MpnModel.csdl|res://*/Model.MpnModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.MpnModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=SRV3;Database=DB1_DEMO;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Indeed, on SRV3 there is also a read/only copy of the production database, DB1, but only as a secondary r/o node.

And nothing in stage application points to DB1 database name.

This is not happening on every SP, but only to few of them.

Any idea what is happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea what is happening?

Here's my guess:  You have some code referring to an object using a 3-part name.  Eg a stored procedure in DB1_DEMO has something like:

```
SELECT ... FROM DB1.DBO.SOMETABLE
```

Comment: I thought so also, and that's the first thing I tried. I used RedGate SQL Search to search for DB1 db name across all objects in the database, but it found nothing. I also manually reviewed the offending SP - also nothing.  There is not a single reference (as far as I can tel from the search of RedGate SQL Search)

Comment: An XEvent trace can capture the errors and the queries that cause them.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try